# Unchecking Radio button in android

Tags: java, android, radio-button

Hello everyone i am developing an quiz based app in android and i have used the radio buttons as the options it has one quest and 4 options for that and 2 buttons to go back to previous quest and next quest. My quest once opens the app for the 1st time all the radio buttons will be unchecked and after answering the 1st quest say he answers 3rd quest and goes to next quest then the radio button will be in the same 3 rd option(but the option will change) i wanted it all the radio buttons to be unchecked when the user goes to next question every time.Can anyone help me out with this..Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clear your radioButtonGroup....

```
radioButtonGroup.clearCheck();
```

Comment: k where it will be better when the user clicks the next button or??

Comment: ya when user click on next button

Answer (score 1):

[RadioButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html) extends [CompountButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html)

Which means that you can also use the method [setChecked(boolean checked);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setChecked%28boolean%29)