# uncheck radio button in android

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I'm newbie in java and having problem with `radioButtondelivery.setSelected(false);` the `radioButtondelivery` is under redline please help me.

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radioButtonpickup:
            if (checked)

                radioButtondelivery.setSelected(false);

            break;
        case R.id.radioButtondelivery:
            if (checked)
                // code here
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unchecking Radio button in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768046/unchecking-radio-button-in-android)

Comment: I do mean inside the switch case how can i call the radioButtondelivery?

Comment: If you hover your mouse over an error, a little popup appears to tell you what the error is.

Comment: yes **radioButtondelivery cannot be resolved** how can i solve this?

Comment: @nic you mean that you can't detect your button?!! this is a totally different question and you asked your question in a wrong way, kindly fix that or ask it as a new question, and for accessing a Button or any view you have to declare it at first, did you did that? like `RadioButton radioButtondelivery = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButtondelivery);` then inside the **switch case** just keep what you are doing by using the generated  variable as it has the same name as the resource `radioButtondelivery.setSelected(false);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `setChecked()`

```
radioButtondelivery.setChecked(false);
```

but you really have to consider using [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) it will automatically uncheck other radio buttons once you select one of them